# Storing text string via email input in Drupal Commerce checkout

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

When a buyer goes through the checkout process as anonymous guest, he specifies his email at the *"Order information"* step in the input

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-contact-information-email" type="email" id="edit-contact-information-email" name="contact_information[email]" value="" size="60" maxlength="254" class="form-email required" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

The email is stored in the column `mail` of the table `commerce_order` of the database.

I would like to store a text string via this input in the database.

If I fill the input by JS with text string and even change the `type` attribute of the input from `email` to `text`, the data is not stored in the DB. So there is email validating somewhere.

Where is the validating in JS or PHP?

Or how can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the hook form_alter.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9

Also, you should take a look into the drupal checkout docs too:

https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/checkout/configure-checkout

**You should be aware that changing a form type may impact all other places that needs to read this data.**

Regarding the hook alter, Here goes an example.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'myformID') {
    $form['myformMachineName']['myfield']['#type'] = 'textfield';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it work only in a module or in `themename.theme` file as well?

Comment: It should work as a theme hook too https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157381/theme-hooks-vs-module-hooks

Comment: When I use the code `if($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default'){$form['contact_information']['email']['#type'] = 'text';}` the input is not displayed in HTML at all... All the keys are proper, I've checked them out

Comment: Sorry, you maybe should use type=textfield instead of text.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/9.3.x here is the reference. I updated the answer, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yes, now it's working and text string is successfully stored in the DB. Perfect! Thank you again!

Comment: danielarand, it was perfectly worked in Drupal 9. But now when I created and configured the shop in Drupal 10, it doesn't work. I see data filled in the input, but it's not stored at the database. What may be a reason?